# Java - Listening on a local port for RTP packets

Tags: java, sockets, rtp

So I am currently working on a client application that listens on port 5004 for RTP packets. Since there may be multiple servers sending RTP packets, I can't use sockets to connect to a specific remote host. Instead, I have tried the following to listen on a local port:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5004);
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5004);
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 5004);
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 5004);
```

Any of the above will give me this exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I have also tried using a DatagramSocket, but DatagramPackets require that I specify the size of the packet to be read.

To summarize, I need to find a way to listen on local port 5004 for RTP packets of unknown size without connecting to a specific remote host/address. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I now have a ServerSocket set up to listen for connections, but I still can't manage to read in any packets.

```
try {   ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5004);
        Socket s = server.accept();
        BufferedReader rtpReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        while (true){
            int k = rtpReader.read();
            if (k == -1) break;
            System.out.println(k);
        }
}
```

Note: The RTP packets are sent over a Multicast address.

The problem turned out to be the Multicast. Refer to Nikolai's answer. Thanks alot!

Comment: If you're listening you should use a `ServerSocket`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`java.net.MulticastSocket`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html), and ***join the multicast group***. Something like:

```
// put your multicast address here
InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName( "244.10.10.10" );
MulticastSocket sock = new MulticastSocket( 5004 );
sock.joinGroup( group );

byte[] buf = new byte[1472];
DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );

while ( whatever ) {
    sock.receive( pack );
    // handle data
}

sock.leaveGroup( group );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new [ServerSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) class, and then use the accept() method to use the Socket created when someone connects to your listening server/ port.

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5004);
Socket s = server.accept();
// You can now use the socket "s"...
```

Comment: You are talking TCP, but OP needs multicast UDP.